# Pandas: Adding zero values where no rows exist (sparse)

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a MultiIndex.  The MultiIndex has values in the range `(0,0)` to `(1000,1000)`, and the column has two fields `p` and `q`.

However, the DataFrame is *sparse*.  That is, if there was no measurement corresponding to a particular index (say `(3,2)`), there won't be *any* row for it `(3,2)`.  I'd like to make it not sparse, by filling in these rows with `p=0 and q=0`. Continuing the example, if I do `df.loc[3].loc[2]`, I want it to return `p=0 q=0`, *not* No Such Record (as it currently does).

*Clarification: By "sparse", I mean it only in the sense I used it, that zero values are omitted.  I'm not referring to anything in Pandas or Numpy internals.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this `df`

```
data = {
    (1, 0): dict(p=1, q=1),
    (3, 2): dict(p=1, q=1),
    (5, 4): dict(p=1, q=1),
    (7, 6): dict(p=1, q=1),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df

     p  q
1 0  1  1
3 2  1  1
5 4  1  1
7 6  1  1
```

---

Use `reindex` with `fill_value=0` from a constructed `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(8), range(8)])
df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)

     p  q
0 0  0  0
  1  0  0
  2  0  0
  3  0  0
  4  0  0
  5  0  0
  6  0  0
  7  0  0
1 0  1  1
  1  0  0
  2  0  0
  3  0  0
  4  0  0
  5  0  0
  6  0  0
  7  0  0
2 0  0  0
  1  0  0
  2  0  0
  3  0  0
```

---

**response to comment**
You can get min, max of index levels like this

```
def mn_mx(idx):
    return idx.min(), idx.max()

mn0, mx0 = mn_mx(df.index.levels[0])
mn1, mx1 = mn_mx(df.index.levels[1])

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(mn0, mx0 + 1), range(mn1, mx1 + 1)])
df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Very cool! Instead of hard coding the range, is there a way to infer the min and max of the corresponding index values? (I only want to fill in values in between the existing extremes).

Comment: @SRobertJames lol!  I just had that in my answer and deleted it.  Oh well.  Yes.  One moment while I update my post.

Comment: Works great! Ensure that the `df.index.is_unique` before trying this.

Comment: Ahh, spoke too soon.  I'm getting MemoryError (top shows 30 GB in use before error, which is all I have!).  The index size is 400 (level 0) * 300 (level 1) * 2000 (level 2) = 240 million, which, at > 100 bytes a row (very reasonable given that `p` and `q` are floats), exhausts 24 GB.  Is there a way to handle this in Pandas? If not, is there an equivalent SQL command (I can load the data into SQL)?

Comment: @SRobertJames at this point we need other mem efficient strategies. Like sparse dataframes. I'll look into it later.